# Apache unable to access local DNS ip address

Tags: apache, dns, ip-address

I just set up a server in my house using private IP.

I can access my server using my domain from outside network/ outside from my house.

But I cannot access it from local network using my domain or my private IP address.

What can be the problem for this? is it the Apache settings?

(I can access it if I edit the /etc/hosts file)

Comment: Running on a non-standard port?  Bound to a machine with multiple IPs and only some are accessible from outside?  What makes you think you can't see the server (you tried `dig`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the internal or external IP in your hosts file to get it working? If it was external IP it's probably the [DNS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534827/1318694). If it was the internal IP, the issue could be in the routers NAT.

Some routers/setups will only apply their NAT rules on packets traversing the external internet facing interface.

```
                 ____________        
                |            |       
Server ---IntIf-|IntIP--ExtIP|-ExtIf--- Internet
                |____________|
```

This is a bit simplified but basically when you access the external IP from the internal network the packet, following the dotted line, reaches the routers external IP before a NAT rule can be applied on `ExtIf` and then the router can't find anything listening so rejects/drops the connection.

To confirm if it is the DNS problem. Run an `nslookup $domain` from both your local and external boxes and see if they return the same IP address. If the IP's are the same and it's still not working you will need to take a closer look at the router, hopefully that's possible. If not you may need an internal DNS server that can respond with the internal IP addresses for any domains it knows about then forward any other requests externally.

The NAT issue is called NAT Loopback, Hairpinning or Reflection. See here for a [linux solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/74182/service-cant-connect-to-self-using-public-ip-nat-problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you can access it when you put in an entry in /etc/hosts, then likely it is DNS related. I am assuming you are putting in the public (external IP) and not an internal IP for testing.

If you have recently updated your DNS, then likely your local router (or ISP's DNS server) will still have the old IP cached or the fact that there is no DNS record setup cached. You could reboot your router to try and clear the cached entry, but it could well be cached at the ISP and you can only wait until it updates there (usually somewhere under 24 hours, often just a few hours). However, you could configure your computer to use a different DNS server for a while - eg. 8.8.8.8 or 4.4.4.4 which are both run by Google.

Comment: i just restarted my router, and it still doesnt work, I'll try to wait for 24 hours